# Donald Cohn measure theory (2e) 1.2.8: prove $\mu^*$ is a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Here is an exercise that I got stuck on from the measure theory book I am currently reading.

Given a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, define $\mu^*:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ as $\mu^*(A) = \sup\{\mu(B): B \in \mathcal{A}, B \subseteq A, \mu(B) < \infty\}$. I need to show $\mu^*$ is a measure.

I couldn't prove the countable additivity case when $\cup_{k}A_k$ has infinite measure. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: If one of $\mu(A_k)$ is infinite, we are done. What can we say about remaining case?

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate? Why we are done if one of $\mu(A_k)$ is infinite?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show $$\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu^\ast(A_k)$$ where $A_k$ are disjoint and $\mu^\ast(\cup A_k) = \infty$. Then if any one of $\mu^\ast(A_k) = \infty$, both sides of equation is $\infty$, hence same. If not, we prove inequality of both direction.

1. ($\le$) Let $B\subset\cup A_k$, $B\in\mathcal{A}$, and $\mu(B)<\infty$. Then $B\cap A_k\subset A_k$ are disjoint, $B\cap A_k\in\mathcal{A}$, and $\mu(B\cap A_k)<\infty$, so $\mu(B\cap A_k)\le\mu^\ast(A_k)$. Thus we have $$\mu(B) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(B\cap A_k)\le\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu^\ast(A_k),$$ and by taking supremum of all such $B$, we get $\mu^\ast(\cup A_k)\le\sum\mu^\ast(A_k)$.
2. ($\ge$) For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mu^\ast(A_k)<\infty$, so for given $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose $B_k\subset A_k$ s.t $B_k\in\mathcal{A}$, $\mu^\ast(A_k)-\varepsilon/2^k<\mu(B_k)\le\mu^\ast(A_k)$. Then $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k\in\mathcal{A}$, $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k\subset\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$, and $B_k$ are disjoint, so $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_k)\le\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu^\ast(A_k)<\infty$. Thus we have $$\mu^\ast\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\right)\ge\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_k)>\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\mu^\ast(A_k)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2^k}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu^\ast(A_k)-\varepsilon.$$ Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have $\mu^\ast(\cup A_k)\ge\sum\mu^\ast(A_k)$.

Hence they are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I get it.